# Does the vertex efficiency include track reconstruction efficiency?

Tags: experimental-physics, large-hadron-collider, data-analysis

Consider a [document](https://atlas.web.cern.ch/Atlas/GROUPS/PHYSICS/PAPERS/SUSY-2016-08/hepdata_info.pdf) of ATLAS collaboration on displaced vertex level efficiency. On the first two pages there is a description of cut-offs required to background free displaced vertex reconstruction.

I'm wondering in several questions:

- Is the vertex level efficiency the same as vertex reconstruction efficiency?
- Does the vertex level efficiency (presented on a figures in the end of the document) include the tracks reconstruction efficiency?
- If the answer on the previous question is 'yes', do the "selected decay products" requirements from the document determine the track reconstruction efficiency?
- If the answer is 'no', what is the expectation for tracks reconstruction efficiencies? Is it $\mathcal{O}(1)$ for the cuts given in the document?

Could you please answer?